# I am trying to merge to integer strings but Dr. Java the program I am using won't let me use ArrayUtils?

Tags: java, arrays, drjava

In this lab, you will be creating a program that merges two arrays of non-negative (equal to or greater than 0) integers. Your program will accept each array as input from the keyboard. You do not know ahead of time how many values will be entered, but you can assume each array will have a maximum length of 10,000 elements. To stop entering values enter a negative number. You may disregard any negative numbers input and not store these in the array.
The elements of the two input arrays should be in increasing order. In other words, each array element must have a value that is greater than or equal to the previous element value. An array may contain repeated elements.
After the two arrays have been input, your program must check to make sure the elements of each array have been entered in order. If an out of order element is found, print the message “ERROR: Array not in correct order”.
Your task is to merge the two input arrays into a new array, with all elements in order, lowest to highest. Print out each of the original arrays entered, followed by the merged array.
Please note that your program must output the arrays with exactly one space between each of the numbers.
Sample Run 1:
Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit

> ```
> 3
> 3
> 5
> 6
> 8
> 9
> -1
> ```

Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit

> ```
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> -5
> ```

First Array:

```
3 3 5 6 8 9
```

Second Array:

```
3 4 5 6
```

Merged Array:

```
3 3 3 4 5 5 6 6 8 9
```

Sample Run 2:
Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit

> ```
> 4
> 5
> 7
> 2
> -1
> ```

Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit

> ```
> 3
> 3
> 3
> 3
> 3
> 3
> -100
> ```

First Array:

```
4 5 7 2
```

Second Array:

```
3 3 3 3 3 3
```

ERROR: Array not in correct order

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.lang.Object;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;



class Main
{

 public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] arrayone = new int[10000];
        int[] arraytwo = new int[10000];
        int [] mergeQ = new int[arrayone.length + arraytwo.length];
        int integers = 0;
        int inte = 0;


        System.out.println("\nEnter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");

         for (int i = 0; i < arrayone.length; i++)
        {
            arrayone[i] = scan.nextInt();
            if (arrayone[i] < 0){
              break;
            } else {integers ++;}
        }


        System.out.println("\nEnter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
        for (int i=0; i<arraytwo.length; i++)
        {
            arraytwo[i] = scan.nextInt();

            if (arraytwo[i] < 0)
            {
                break;
            } {inte ++;}
        }


        System.out.println("First Array:");
        for (int i=0; i< integers; i++)
        {
          System.out.print(arrayone[i] + " ");
        }


        System.out.println("\nSecond Array:");
        for (int i=0; i< inte; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arraytwo[i] + " ");
        }

      System.out.println("\nMerged Array:");{


        String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(arrayone[integer], arraytwo[inte]);
          Arrays.sort(both);

        }

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: do `int[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayone, 0,integer-1), Arrays.copyOfRange(arraytwo,0,inte-1));`

Comment: This fixed it...I just had to change '"integer" to "integers"...Thanks for the help!!

Comment: `int[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(Arrays.copyOf(arrayone, integers-1), Arrays.copyOf(arraytwo,inte-1));` try this

Comment: Figured it out right when I looked over the error...thanks again!!

Comment: @Minato why is it printing Int Both as "Merged Array:
[I@a166bd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you were adding elements but not the arrays themselves.
```

In you second loop

```
}{ inte++; }
```

change this to

```
}else {inte ++;}
```

one solution could be

```
int[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(Arrays.copyOf(arrayone, integers), Arrays.copyOf(arraytwo,inte));
Arrays.sort(both);
for (int i=0; i< both.length; i++){
      System.out.print(both[i] + " ");
```

A very bad way to do it.. but will work in your CS class

```
for (int i=0; i< integers; i++){
   mergeQ[i] = arrayone[i];
}
for (int i=integers; i< inte + integers; i++){
   mergeQ[i] = arraytwo[i - integers];
}
int both[] = Arrays.copyOf(mergeQ,integers+inte);
Arrays.sort(both);
for (int i=0; i< both.length; i++){
    System.out.print(both[i] + " ");
}
```

## Note: this way is pretty evil.. memory inefficient.. etc..

Here is another way it is a bit cleaner but roughly has the same performance as the one above..

```
System.arraycopy(arrayone, 0, mergeQ, 0, integers);
System.arraycopy(arraytwo, 0, mergeQ, integers, inte);
int both[] = Arrays.copyOf(mergeQ,integers+inte);
Arrays.sort(both);
for (int i=0; i< both.length; i++){
    System.out.print(both[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: The code you shared is compiling but I am receiving this as the output [I@5b4bc4e6

Comment: @WilliamGuyton can you share the first array: and the second: ?

Comment: Well as you can see from the original code from above, each array is inputted manually by the user. The array breaks when a user enters a negative number and then the second array begins receiving user inputted data. The two arrays are supposed to first be printed and then combined in numerical order.

Comment: any ideas on what I can do to fix that?

Comment: What the heck...so the program my computer science class uses CODERUNNER said that it had an error. Main.java:292: error: cannot find symbol
        int[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(Arrays.copyOf(arrayone, integers), Arrays.copyOf(arraytwo,inte));
                     ^
  symbol:   variable ArrayUtils
  location: class Main
1 error

Comment: @WilliamGuyton your CS class doesn't have Apache Commons lang.. which you are using to merge the arrays

Comment: Is there a way to do it without apache commons language?

Comment: @WilliamGuyton I suppose you are not familiar with lists.. right?

Comment: I have very limited knowledge on them. I just really want to figure out the alternative method of doing ordered concatenation, because from the research I've done, it seems the way you showed me is the most straightforward,

Comment: @WilliamGuyton I updated my answer with an other way

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain the inner workings of your code to me. I understand that some users feel im leeching for answers and such. Honestly Im just trying to get the best understanding of this difficult subject that I can.